# concatenate CLOB data in oracle

Tags: oracle, clob

I need to concatenate various CLOB data into a single CLOB field.

I have a database with various rows, each containing a few char fields (BATCH_ID for example), and a CLOB (BATCH_BODY). I am unsure as to how to concatenate the CLOBs in order to make everything a single row.

the end goal is to group together all rows in which the BATCH_ID is the same into a single row with a single CLOB file that is made up of various BATCH_BODY's

Answer (score 5):

CONCAT works with CLOBs it seems:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm

Answer (score 1):

To work with CLOBs longer than 32K without truncation, I needed code like this:

```
--ALL_XML := ALL_XML || SINGLE_XML;
--The above crashed on Oracle 11g with text beyond 32K, so...
lobLength := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(SINGLE_XML);
FOR i IN 0..100 LOOP
    offset := i * buffSize + 1;
    EXIT WHEN SINGLE_XML IS NULL OR lobLength < offset;
    -- fill the buffer with final data chunk to append to the lob
    buffer := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(SINGLE_XML, buffSize, offset);
    DBMS_LOB.APPEND(ALL_XML, TO_CLOB(buffer));
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbms_lob.copy(p_out_clob, p_in_clob, dbms_lob.getlength(p_in_clob), dbms_lob.getlength(p_out_clob));
```

Comment: Even simpler: dbms_lob.append(p_out_clob, p_in_clob);